# Cannot make docker compose run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Vue Django app and I am trying to make it run on Docker but I keep getting the following error:

failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1629661636/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.10 python3-pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev python3-dev


COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "1.1"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/backend
    env_file: .env
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
  frontend:
    build: ../frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ../frontend/src:/frontend/src
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

What am I doing wrong and secondly why is it looking for what seems to be a tmp file?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is my directory structure

```
├── backend
│   ├── ads
│   ├── api
│   ├── companies
│   ├── connections
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── founderslooking
│   ├── locations
│   ├── mail
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── notifications
│   ├── pages
│   ├── payments
│   ├── pitches
│   ├── posts
│   ├── profiles
│   ├── projects
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── services
│   ├── static
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── storage
│   ├── templates
│   ├── users
│   └── usersettings
├── frontend
│   ├── babel.config.js
│   ├── jsconfig.json
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── vue.config.js
├── frontend.tar.gz
├── Pipfile
└── Pipfile.lock
```

Comment: What directory is the Dockerfile actually in?  Is the filename exactly `Dockerfile`, with only a capital `D` and no extension?  The `build: .` requires it to be in the same directory as the Compose file, and the error message pretty much just says "it's not there".  (Ignore the `.../tmp/...` path, this is an internal Docker detail.)

Comment: Updated my question to show what the directory structure is exactly

Comment: You're missing `Dockerfile` in `frontend` folder, ignore the tmp part - it's internal detail (temporary build context created in temp directory). And why does your frontend contain Pipfile? (In future, please post `tree` output for directory structure representation - it's usually slightly more readable and much less error-prone than listing manually)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, Dockerfile could not be found. Please organize your file structure.

**OPTION1:** If your file structure:

```
project-root/
  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt
  - ...
  - docker-compose.yml
  - .env
```

**Docker-compose.yaml:**

```
   ... 
   services:
      backend:
        build:
          context: ./  # the context where your Dockerfile is located
          dockerfile: Dockerfile  # the name of your Dockerfile
   ...
```

Pls run command where docker-compose.yaml file is:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

**OPTION2:** If your file structure:

```
project-root/
  - backend/
    - Dockerfile
    - requirements.txt
    - ...
  - docker-compose.yml
  - .env
```

**Docker-compose.yaml:**

```
...
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend  # the context where your Dockerfile is located
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  # the name of your Dockerfile
...
```

In addition, you can also change the `Dockerfile` name to `Dockerfile_backend`. After that, you should update the docker-compose file.

```
...
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend  # the context where your Dockerfile is located
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_backend
...
```

**EDIT:**

According to your file structure in your post, the Dockerfile for the frontend is missing.

Please organize it like this after adding the Dockerfile for frontend:

```
project
- docker-compose.yml
- backend
-- .env
-- Dockerfile_backend
-- manage.py
-- requirements.txt
- frontend
-- Dockerfile_frontend
-- Pipfile
-- Pipfile.lock
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
...
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend  
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_backend
    ..
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend  
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_frontend
...
```

Run `"docker-compose up -d"` where "docker-compose.yaml" is.

Comment: Updated my question to show the structure

Comment: @crawlingdev I added the EDIT part according to ur file structure.